# use xpath to select elements with a set of multiple attributes/values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document that i need to strip out particular pieces of data

the xml document has a structure as follows:-

```
<a>
   <b select='yes please'>
       <c d='text1' e='text11'/>
       <c d='text2' e='text12'/>
       <c d='text3' e='text13'/>
       <c d='text4' e='text14'/>
       <c d='text5' e='text15'/>
   </b>
 </a>
<a>
   <b select='no thanks'>
       <c d='text1' e='text21'/>
       <c d='text3' e='text23'/>
       <c d='text5' e='text25'/>
   </b>
 </a>
<a>
   <b select='yes please'>
       <c d='text1' e='text31'/>
       <c d='text2' e='text32'/>
       <c d='text3' e='text33'/>
       <c d='text4' e='text34'/>
       <c d='text5' e='text35'/>
   </b>
 </a>
<a>
   <b select='no thanks'>
       <c d='text4' e='text41'/>
       <c d='text3' e='text43'/>
       <c d='text5' e='text45'/>
   </b>
 </a>
```

i need to select only those /a/b element groups that have d attribute = 'text1' and
d attribute = 'text4', once i have identified these sub documents i want to get the value of the e attributes with d attribute value 'text5'

hope thats clear

Cheers

DD

Comment: +1 for xpath/xslt sunday question :)

Comment: ops, it's saturday...

Comment: @empo, In some zones is Sunday already :-)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a single XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted attributes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
//a[b/c/@d = 'text1' and b/c/@d = 'text4']/b/c[@d = 'text5']/@e
```

It will select `e='text15'` and `e='text35'` of 1st and 3rd `a/b`

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="//a[b/c/@d = 'text1' and b/c/@d = 'text4']/b/c[@d = 'text5']">
  <xsl:value-of select="@e"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @user423199, You can mark as answer or upvote appropriate answer.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But I can think this as a subtle downvote, referring to the fact that you predicate on the ancestor `a` of `c`, while (as shown in other answers) it would be more natural predicate  on the immediate parent `b` of `c`. You loose also readability.

Comment: @empo, But if it is so "subtle", @downvoter could explain his opinion. I don't like silent @downvoters.

Answer (score 5):

> i need to select only those /a/b element groups that have d attribute = 'text1' and d attribute = 'text4', once i have identified these sub documents i want to get the value of the e attributes with d attribute value 'text5'
>
> hope thats clear

Yes, it's so clear the translation into XPath is almost mechanical

```
(: those /a/b element groups :) a/b 
(: that have d attribute = 'text1' :) [c/@d='text1'] 
(: and d attribute = 'text4' :) [c/@d='text4'] 
(: and .. i want to get the value of the e attributes 
   with d attribute value 'text5' :) / c[@d='text5'] / @e
```

Comment: FYI- For those not familiar, `(: :)` are XPath 2.0 comments. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#prod-xpath-Comment If you are using XPath 1.0, remove the comments and just use the XPath statement i.e. `a/b[c/@d='text1'][c/@d='text4']/c[@d='text5']/@e`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single template to match the required group, and then you get the value of the required attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/a/b[c[@d='text1'] and c[@d='text4']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="c[@d='text5']/@e"/>
</xsl:template>
```

assuming:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b select='yes please'>
            <c d='text1' e='text11'/>
            <c d='text2' e='text12'/>
            <c d='text3' e='text13'/>
            <c d='text4' e='text14'/>
            <c d='text5' e='text15'/>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b select='no thanks'>
            <c d='text1' e='text21'/>
            <c d='text3' e='text23'/>
            <c d='text5' e='text25'/>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b select='yes please'>
            <c d='text1' e='text31'/>
            <c d='text2' e='text32'/>
            <c d='text3' e='text33'/>
            <c d='text4' e='text34'/>
            <c d='text5' e='text35'/>
        </b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b select='no thanks'>
            <c d='text4' e='text41'/>
            <c d='text3' e='text43'/>
            <c d='text5' e='text45'/>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

the output will be `text15` and `text35`.

Comment: thanks for bothering to look at my problem, it was driving me mad! thankyou for spending time on it

Comment: @user you are welcome. The "tricky" part here is matching an element for which we have at least two instances of same children with different attribute value. You need to use _and_ and, for clarity, a nested predicate.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this single XPath expression**:

```
/*/a/b[c/@d='text1' and c/@d='text4']
         /c[@d='text5']
             /@e
```